# Converting python file into android file using Kivy buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I converted the python file into APK file by using Kivy Buildozer. Then I deploy the APK file in my mobile. But it's not working. the app is getting started and showing loading then closed automatically.so is there any extra module required to import?

Comment: Could be something missing. Try the command `buildozer  android debug logcat run`. This should show you the `logcat` logging and may show a hint as to what went wrong.

Comment: Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,jinja2,openssl,requests,simplejson --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/ansuman/Desktop/simpleapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

Comment: its showing that pythonforandroid.toolchain  module is not there so how to handle it.i am using ndk=r18

Comment: this is my full log